# Bind PowerShell function to parameter

Tags: powershell

Is it possible in PowerShell (or even better in PowerShell Core) to bind a function to a parameter ValidateSet specified to the script?

I want to bind the parameter options `a`, `b` and `c` to the functions `a_function` `b_function` and `c_function` to the variable `$firstcmd` or `$secondcmd` . Therefore if the script is called by

```
PS C:\ script.ps1 a
```

the function `a` is run.

if the script is called by

```
PS C:\ script.ps1 a b
```

the functions `a` and `b` are run.

The parameter definition at script start looks like this:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String][ValidateSet('a',
                                                        'b',
                                                        'c')$firstcmd,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String][ValidateSet('a',
                                                        'b', 
                                                        'c')$secondcmd,
     )

function a_function {
    Write-Host "Hello a"
}

function b_function  {
    Write-Host "Hello b"
}

function c_function  {
    Write-Host "Hello c"
}

# here the "command option to function mapping" magic should happen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved by a Switch statement to call a specific function but I think what you are looking for is a more elegant lookup. One possible option is a hash table + the call operator (&):

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String][ValidateSet('a',
                                                        'b',
                                                        'c')] $firstcmd,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String][ValidateSet('a',
                                                        'b', 
                                                        'c')] $secondcmd
     )

function a_function {
    Write-Host "Hello a"
}

function b_function  {
    Write-Host "Hello b"
}

function c_function  {
    Write-Host "Hello c"
}

#hash table:
$ParamToFunction = @{
    a = "a_function"
    b = "b_function"
    c = "c_function"
}

#function calls:
& $ParamToFunction[$firstcmd]
& $ParamToFunction[$secondcmd]
```

Of course it will throw an error if you don't provide a value for any parameter - I leave it to you to handle such cases.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted. Additionally I wrapped the function calls in `if ($firstcmd) { & $ParamToFunction[$firstcmd] }`, because my parameters are not mandatory.

Comment: is it also possible to pass an argument to that table?